# XStream read back xml (java)

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have an xml with a format like this:

```
<list>
<book>
    <price>20</price>
    <author>sam</author>
    <features type="comic">
        <pocket>yes</pocket>
    </features>
    <avaiable>yes</avaiable>
</book>
<book>
    <price>50</price>
    <author>john</author>
    <features type="novel">
        <manga>no</manga>
    </features>
    <avaiable>yes</avaiable>
</book>
</list>
```

what I need is to read first the feature type, since this attribute is needed to know wich class I need to instantate in java. I've tryed to read until this node, and then moveUp() to the book node again...but when I try to go down again to get the rest of node values its not possible...seems like it's not possible to read  again the nodes once you have go down

So my question is: is there a way to get first an especific node and then move back to read the other nodes ?

Comment: Do you really need to use XStream for this?  It's perhaps not the best choice for this problem.

Comment: Yeah, its the library we use. And until know its been really easy to work with it...but know we I have faced this problem

Comment: I would suggest to first un-marshall the XML into Java objects that map the XML structure (with a feature member) and create your specialized Java objects (with the different classes) from there.

Comment: Mmm sounds an option but i would be creating two objects...What I'm finally doing is to use xpath to get the feature node to instante the class and then do the normall unmarshalling. I don't like the idea of using to different libraries to do this, but it's the simple way I came with